# Clubbed total sale for month using PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get a total sale from the given table. Where showing total daily sale and the grand total at the end. My table is like:

```
Date        | Bill No. | Product | Amount | Total Bill Amt. |
01/04/2015  | 001      |  A      | 150    | 650 <<          |
01/04/2015  | 001      |  B      | 300    | 650             |
01/04/2015  | 001      |  C      | 200    | 650             |
01/04/2015  | 002      |  B      | 10     |  80 <<          |
01/04/2015  | 002      |  D      | 70     |  80             |
02/04/2015  | 003      |  Z      | 60     | 110 <<          |
02/04/2015  | 003      |  Y      | 50     | 110             |
```

Where results should be:

```
Date       |  Total Sale  |
01/04/2015 |   730        |
02/04/2015 |   190        |
```

Comment: How `01/04/2015 |   730 ` you get 730 ? what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: 730 is total of sale for 1st April 2015. (650 + 80 = 730)

Comment: How do you get the value of your `Total Bill Amt.`? What calculation goes there?

Comment: Is there a primary key in the table ? you are storing the same bill per sales in multiple rows which has one billing amount, which could have been much better if you would have implemented a different table for line items.

Comment: When user enters a bill, program save the multiple products in different row where bill number remains the same and Total Bill Amount remain the same.

Comment: Ok so you may just sum up the amount and do a group by date. However if you want that to be by total bill amount how for `02/04/2015` is `190` ? Should't it be `110` And also is there a primary key auto-incremented ?

Answer (score 2):

For `02/04/2015`, it should be `110` and not `190`.

```
SELECT `Date`,SUM(`Amount`) AS daily_sale FROM `table` GROUP BY `Date`.
```

Comment: ok. yeh. let me try.

Comment: I neet to run query on Total Bill Amt. column not on Amount...

Comment: If you run it on Total Bill Amount, you will have to group by Bill No. and then do a sum, which will be the same as returned by the query above. Any idea why you want to group by Total Bill Amt.

Comment: I need to calculate it on Total Bill Amount because, the given table is a sample. Actual table contains a couple of columns for tax and discount which consists in Total Bill Amout

Answer (score 0):

To get the different days dates, depending on the structure of your table, I assume you have a column for `id` which is a `primary key` to help track all those `table rows` by `id`.

To get the daily `Total Bill Amt`, apply same query format used by @web-normad annd you'll get your total.

```
SELECT DATE(Date),SUM(Total Bill Amt) AS daily_sale FROM `table` GROUP BY `Date`.
```

Test it out and see if it works.

Comment: I tried this query:    SELECT date, billNo, SUM(afterRound) FROM retailbilling GROUP BY date IN (SELECT date, billNo, afterRound FROM retailbilling WHERE MONTH(date)= 4 GROUP BY billNo ORDER BY billNo ASC);    Can you please help correcting this.. getting error... #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Please what are you trying to achieve with your query because what you are doing is now different from your question.

Comment: OK. I am trying to generate a report where I need monthly sale, let say "APRIL"... it should be grouped "DATE WISE". Means total sale of 1st April, 2nd April, 3rd April... So on.. in every row.

Comment: Did you try the query I posted and it didn't give you what you wanted? What error did it give to you if it didn't work so we start troubleshooting from there. Moreso, please edit your question to show that you actually are trying to generate a monthly report sorted by date. It will help other coders to easily help you get your solution.

Comment: It is giving 2110 for 1/4/2015 (Calculating as... 650 + 650 + 650 + 80 +80) where it should be 650 + 80

Comment: You are the one confusing the entire process. Remember when I asked you the calculation that goes on at the `Total Bill Amt` and what was your answer again? Query is absolutely right but values you are inserting into columns are wrong. You need fix up your database tables well. It's better you designate a table that will take total daily sales and get it away from where you have it currently. That's the best way to resolve your issue.

Comment: it could be a solution, but there should be a way to generate report by writing a query instead of creating a new table?